# How to get a minimum and maximum point from a las file ?

Tags: c++, liblas

I wish to get the minimum and maximum point from a las file. Following the documentation, I could read and write a .las file. However, I couldn't get idea how to get the minimum and maximum points. I could get minimum or maximum x ,y ,z individually.However, I want to see the point that is maximum or minimum. Any suggestions

Comment: how do you define "minimum" and "maximum" for threedimensional data?

Comment: My  assumption is (x,y,z) coordinate less than other point is minimum and viceversa is maximum. Might be I am wrong. I  need a boundary after reading a .las file .

Comment: again, how do you define "less" for 3D points? please specify what you need this "boundary" for, this will help finding a solution.

Comment: @m.s. is right "minimum" and "maximum" for 3D points is not defined since it only applies to entities with a natural linear order. May be the [euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Three_dimensions) from the origin of your coordinate system might help.

Comment: @m.s Suppose there are 1000 points  in a .las file. I wish to see a boundary or might be a range  that means two points . I say them minimum Point and maximum Point . If, I iterate through this points , I will get the whole points. My apology, if I couldn't make things clear again.

Comment: @user3421760: Unfortunately, this is still unclear. Note that you might establish an arbitrary order (lexicographical order of the individual components, for example), or not care about ordering at all (either just seeking the minimum and maximum values of each component or just wanting to be able to iterate over them). It is likely that you wish to accomplish *something* by iterating over those points, and maybe some context could help guide the advice you are asking for.

Comment: I made my question unclear. Sorry for everyone. Could anybody, give a simple working example of liblas filters with bound. I could understand from that.